# How to write documentation in attribute definition in Dynamics CRM

Tags: documentation, dynamics-crm, customization

I'm searching a way to describe the purpose of custom attribute inside the attribute definition - similar to describing a Column purpose in SQL. There is already a field called description, but it is used for tooltip to display more extensive description to the user.

Is there anything I'm missing or that can be used to achieve a inline documentation in the system?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, I would use the description field and pick something that is okay to show to the user.